# what changes should be done in AndroidManifest when add a jar library

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm developing an app. in my app I need a download manager so I search at GitHub and found a download.jar library which could do this job for me.
I add this library to libs folder of my project and then I can access to it's classes, but when I run my app, at the time I call the activity associated to that library app give error.
should I change the android manifest to access to that activity?
for more definition I put a button and declare this listener for it:

> public void startDownload(View v)
>   {
>   DownloadTask downloadTask6 = new DownloadTask("http://cdn.p30download.com/?b=p30dl-video&f=Collateral.Beauty.2016.1080p.mkv_p30download.com.part1.rar", null, "sa.rar", "as", null);
>           DownloadTaskManager.getInstance(this).registerListener(downloadTask6, new DownloadNotificationListener(this, downloadTask6));
>           DownloadTaskManager.getInstance(this).startDownload(downloadTask6);
>   }

and when I click it give this error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                      Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0xffffffff
>                         at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:229)
>                         at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:313)
>                         at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:292)
>                         at com.zxt.download2.DownloadNotificationListener.initNotifiction(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.zxt.download2.DownloadNotificationListener.(Unknown Source)
>                         at com.example.arm.simpledownload.MainActivity.starttttyys(MainActivity.java:56)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>   Application terminated.

Comment: Can you please add your error message ?

Comment: "should I change the android manifest to access to that activity? " -- ask the developer of the library that you are trying to use.

Comment: I tried to ask but I gave no response.

Comment: error added to question

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Put the .jar into the `libs` folder

**2)** Right click it and hit `'Add as library'`

**3)** `Clean Project` and `Build Gradle` then you are good to go.

Comment: I sad in my definition that I add library successfully but when in my app I call an activity associated to that library it lead to error.